# Relacionamento de duas Tabelas com um DataSet contendo duas Tabelas

Tags: c#

Boa Tarde pessoal

Necessito da ajuda para fazer o **relacionamento de duas tabelas,** para ao clicar no DataGridView do DG_TitulosaReceber, apareça no DG_NumerodeParcelas de baixo  as parcelas de cada título.

Quero criar o **Sincronismo das duas tabelas**, para no load, mostrar o registro do **título a receber no DataGridView de cima**, e mostrar as respectivas parcelas (deste título) **no DataGridView de baixo**. Inclusive utilizando um botão, **próximo** e **voltar**, de modo que troque para os próximos registros, vinculando o Título a receber e suas parcelas.

No FormLoad deve ser carregado, vinculando o Titulo a receber (1º DataGridView)(1ªtabela Títulos a receber) com o Numero de Parcelas daquele título (2º DataGridView)(2ªtabela Numero de Parcelas a receber).

Sem o relacionamento, consigo fazer o Load, mas sem sincronismo. Não dá erro, com o relacionamento que tentei fazer está abortando ao abrir o formulário.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
public partial class Entrada_Titulos_a_Receber : Form
{
    private DataSet TitulosareceberRelacionamento;


    private void Entrada_Titulos_a_Receber_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // Criando a Relação entre Tabelas Entrada_Titulos_a_Receber X Numero_Parcelas_a_Receber

         TitulosareceberRelacionamento = new DataSet();
         DataRelation data_relationReceber = new DataRelation(
              "EntradaTitulosReceberXNumeroParcelas",
              TitulosareceberRelacionamento
                          .Tables["Entrada_Titulos_a_Receber"]
                          .Columns["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1"],  
              TitulosareceberRelacionamento
                          .Tables["Numero_Parcelas_a_Receber"]
                          .Columns["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn14"]);

         TitulosareceberRelacionamento.Relations.Add(data_relationReceber);

         this.numero_Parcelas_a_ReceberTableAdapter
                  .Fill(this.sGFRenaissanceDataSetEntradaTitulosReceberXnumeroParcelas
                                        .Numero_Parcelas_a_Receber);
         this.entrada_Titulos_a_ReceberTableAdapter
                  .Fill(this.sGFRenaissanceDataSetEntradaTitulosReceberXnumeroParcelas
                                        .Entrada_Titulos_a_Receber);

         // this.entrada_Titulos_a_ReceberBindingSource.DataSource = DataContextFactory.DataContext.Entrada_Titulos_a_Recebers;
         // this.numeroParcelasaReceberBindingSource.DataSource = DataContextFactory.DataContext.Numero_Parcelas_a_Recebers;


     }
}
```

Obs.: Sistem aborta ao tentar abrir o Formulário.
Resposta do Visual Studio, ao Abrir o Formulário Entrada_Titulos_a_Receber:

**NullReferenceException Was Unhandlded**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in SGFRenaissance.exe Additional information: Referência de
>   objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.
>
> Trobleshooting tips: Check to determine if the object is null before
>   calling the method. use the "new" keyword to create an object
>   instance. Get General help for this exception
>
> **View Detail...**  (mensagem do sistema)
>
> System.NullReferenceException {"Referência de objeto não definida para
>   uma instância de um objeto."}

Solicito a ajuda de vocês para Criar o relacionamento das Tabelas pois no DataSource SGFDaRenaissanceDataSetEntradaTitulosReceberXnumeroParcelas
foi criado no Wizard como "Relacionamento" Sem chave secundária "ForeignKey" pois utilizando as Chaves no relacionamento dava erro.

Criei o DataSet acima, com o Wizard (criando a query com as duas tabelas) e funcionou exibindo o conteúdo das tabelas corretamente. Verifiquei o funcionamento no SQL Server - tudo ok.
As duas Tabelas estão juntas no DataSet acima, arrastei a primeira para um DataGridView, e a segunda para o outro DataGridView.
Estão com os campos corretamente nos DataGridView. Quando abro o formulário, (sem o código de relacionamento) os grids são preenchidos normalmente. Mas com o relacionamento das tabelas dá erro.

**Estrutura das Tabelas:**

```
Entrada_Titulos_a_Receber - Titulo       
Cod_Entrada_Titulos_a_Receber -> Int ----> chavePrimaria - Identity yes
Cod_Cliente               -> Int
Numero_NF                 -> Varchar(20)
Data_NF                    -> Datetime
Valor_NF                   -> Decimal(18,2)
Cod_Receita                -> Int
Data_Vencimento             -> Datetime
Numero_Parcelas            -> Decimal(3,0)
Valor_Pago_a_Vista         -> Decimal(18,2)
Cod_Status_Titulo          -> Int
Historico                 -> Varchar(50)
Data_Login                -> Datetime
Login_Name                -> Varchar(15)
--------------------------------------------------
Numero_Parcelas_a_Receber
Cod_Entrada_Titulos_a_Receber -> Int ----> chavePrimaria Recebe o valor da 
                                                         Primeira tabela
Cod_Numero_Parcelas_Receber -> Int ----> chavePrimaria - Identity yes
Numero_Parcela         -> Decimal(3,0)
Data_Vencimento        -> Datetime
Valor_Parcela         -> Decimal(18,2)
Historico             -> Varchar(25)
Cod_Status_Titulo     -> Int
```

As tabelas estão com 3 registros na primeira, e seis na segunda (numero de parcelas)
Será que deve ser criado um DataSet para cada tabela ? mas como seria o relacionamento?

Muitíssimo obrigado pela ajuda.
Flávio Rocha.

Comment: Debugando, onde ocorre o erro?

Comment: really?? `sGFRenaissanceDataSetEntradaTitulosReceberXnumeroParcelas`

Comment: O erro ocorre na abertura do formulário. Quando chamo no menu principal, no form Load, ele para. Está no código que enviei, as mensagens de erro quando o sistema aborta.

Comment: Onde, em qual linha?

Comment: Leandro, no load do Formulário Entrada_Titulos_a_Receber.cs linha 48